# joomla forms - changing properties and fields

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have started working on a joomla project from the middle and can't contact the previous
programmer. The site I'm working on has a form that is displayed on the front page but entering the module doesn't give details about how to edit the form - it's a module of type "mod-form" but no parameters for the module. is it probable that an extension is used or that is a joomla built-in form? (is there such a thing?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for the form code in 'joomla folder'/components/com_contact/
And for the colors,positions you can search in your template directory for the css file, and edit the values referring to the form, like inputbox, input.button and etc.

Answer (score 0):

A module to display a form is most certainly connected to a component that allows you to administer the forms. Take a look in the Components in the admin, there is likely a component there for that purpose. The standard Joomla install does not have a mod_form so this is definitely an extension.